# Rename [Hillary] to [Hillary-Clinton]

Tags: discussion, tags

Someone created the [hillary](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hillary) tag, most likely for Hillary Clinton. The tag should be renamed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just deleted the tag because it's a meta-tag.  Individual politicians don't need their own tags.

Comment: Did you delete [tag:donald-trump] and [tag:barack-obama] while you were at it?