# How should we deal with tags that refer to individuals?

Tags: discussion, tags

This [answer](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2590/28994) from 2016 seems to suggest that tags of this kind are meta-tags and should be deleted. Should we apply this logic to the current individual-specific tags, or should we allow them in certain circumstances? Below is a list of the current individual-specific tags that I'm aware of.

[barack-obama](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/barack-obama)[bernie-sanders](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bernie-sanders)[bill-clinton](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bill-clinton)[boris-johnson](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boris-johnson)[che-guevara](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/che-guevara)[donald-trump](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/donald-trump)[elizabeth-warren](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elizabeth-warren)[emmanuel-macron](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emmanuel-macron)[george-w-bush](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/george-w-bush)[hillary-clinton](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hillary-clinton)[hugo-chavez](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hugo-chavez)[imran-khan](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/imran-khan)[jeremy-corbyn](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jeremy-corbyn)[joe-biden](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joe-biden)[julian-assange](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/julian-assange)[justin-trudeau](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/justin-trudeau)[leopoldo-lopez](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leopoldo-lopez)[marine-le-pen](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marine-le-pen)[michael-bloomberg](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/michael-bloomberg)[mike-pence](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mike-pence)[putin](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/putin)[recep-tayyip-erdogan](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recep-tayyip-erdogan)[richard-nixon](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/richard-nixon)[rodrigo-duterte](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rodrigo-duterte)[ronald-reagan](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ronald-reagan)[sadiq-khan](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sadiq-khan)[steve-bannon](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steve-bannon)[theresa-may](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theresa-may)[vladimir-putin](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vladimir-putin)

At the very least, we should agree on what style to use - above are examples of firstname-lastname, firstname-middle-last, & just last name. If we standardise this, we can avoid duplicates such as [putin](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/putin) & [vladimir-putin](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vladimir-putin).

Comment: Related question (and certainly more recent than the 2016 one and with more votes) https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4155/should-we-rollback-composite-tags-in-particular-trump-impeachment

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I find these tags pretty useful and believe they should stay. Although there is some misuse occasionally. Like in [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/50330/does-the-us-president-have-the-right-to-micromanage-the-us-department-of-justi) which was tagged as [donald-trump](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/donald-trump) even though it is about the political powers of the President of the United States in general and not specific to Trump. But on the other hand we have questions which definitely are about specific politicians, like for example the recent HNQ "[What caused Mike Bloomberg to win American Samoa?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/50709/what-caused-mike-bloomberg-to-win-american-samoa)" which is clearly about a specific politician and as such should be tagged for that politician.

So we should be vigilant and make sure that person-tags don't get applied to questions which aren't actually about that person. Keep in mind that just because a question mentions a person as an example or to provide context doesn't mean that it is about that person. The litmus test for when you should apply a tag should be "Would someone who is an expert on [person] be qualified to answer this question?" and "Would someone who wants to know more about [person] be particularly interested in this question?".

Regarding the naming: I think we should stick to the "firstname-lastname" convention, except in cases where there is ambiguity. I retagged the one question which was tagged as [putin](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/putin) as [vladimir-putin](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vladimir-putin)

Answer (score 1):

The key here is you need one or both of these conditions

1. Multiple questions related to the person
2. A high profile poltician

A US President or UK Prime Minister would easily qualify. Recip Erdogan also looks like a good candidate. A major party candidate... maybe (Tulsi Gabbard and Tom Steyer were too minor in 2020). Someone like Leopoldo Lopez... not at all (good luck knowing who he is without Google or [the one question about him](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/39983/did-leopoldo-lopez-take-part-in-a-coup-against-hugo-chavez)).